# RDF.rb - ruby sparql-client gem sparql query "select " not working

Tags: rubygems, rdf, sparql

I am using the [bendiken/sparql-client](https://github.com/bendiken/sparql-client)  for ruby application.When I execute the given sample query methods its returning any empty array result.

The query method is as follow:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sparql/client'
sparql = SPARQL::Client.new("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
query = sparql.select.where([:s, :p, :o]).offset(100).limit(10)
query.each_solution do |solution|
  puts solution.inspect
end
```

If I execute with following query it is returning result perfectly .

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sparql/client'
sparql = SPARQL::Client.new("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
queryString="SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } OFFSET 100 LIMIT 10"
query= sparql.query(queryString)
query.each_solution do |solution|
  puts solution.inspect
end
```

Please Let me know why the first query method is not working.Let me know if any thing I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your first sample does not work, since it does seem to match the documentation. It didn't work for me either, with the 0.0.9 sparql-client gem. However, calling `query.execute` does run the query. So:

```
sparql = SPARQL::Client.new("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
query = sparql.select.where([:s, :p, :o]).offset(100).limit(10)
query.execute.each do |solution|
  puts solution.inspect
end
```

works for me

Comment: Thanks for the your answer.Now It is working :).But why they given  not working example?